# How to bypass records with case

Tags: sql-server

I have got a CTE with this sort of data

```
ID | Name | UserID | SupervisorID
1.   Mark      1           2
2.   John      1           1
3.   Julia     3           1
4.   Tomm      1           2
5.   Eric      2           2
```

And if the SupervisorID is equal 2, then the rows with UserID equal 1 should NOT be returned.
If the SupervisorID is equal 1, then the rows with UserID equal 1 should NOT be returned.

I have tried with this query, but got stuck and can't figure out how to solve this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE UserID <> CASE SupervisorID WHEN 1 THEN ??
```

Comment: WHERE NOT (SupervisorID = 2 AND UserID = 1)

Comment: didn't understand?

Comment: OK, got it. I did it myself and then noticed that you have edited your answer. Anyway, thank you very much, I've been trying for few hours how to achive that :)
Thank you one more time bro!